# web-service hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, database, web-services, sql-server-2005

I create a web-service in asp.NET. It works as I need. i.e. I can test it in the browser and connect to the database properly. After that, I host it in the IIS Manager. Now, when I try to test the methods from the hosted web-service (the one in the IIS), it shows me a web page with:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Student'

Where `Student` is one of my database tables I use it in the method in a SELECT query. I don't know what happened and how to solve it!!

Comment: We need to see some web service code ... guessing here that it is either connecting to the wrong database, or the credentials the ws is connecting with has a default schema different to what you expect ... try prefixing with the schema, e.g. `dbo.Student`

Comment: you should set web.config and connectionstring

Comment: @StuartLC I connect the correct database. and I didn't understand what you mean by ws credential!! Should I try to add dbo.Student instead of Student in the query? or where?

Comment: @Iraj this is my connectionString: <add name="sbms" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />